# How to persist the changes, even an error is occured with in try catch in flyway?

Tags: flyway

I am using flyway and I have a procedure, which will migrate employees. In the procedure I am using try/catch block and using begin/commit transaction within the while loop of processing employee. If any error is occurring with a row, it will skip to next employee. But after processing all employees, the flyway is rolling back the entire migration if there is an exception in at least one row. Is there any solution to persist those employees which is being migrated successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Flyway only rolls back if a SQL Exception is thrown. Double-check your code to make sure it is correct.